# Rails page specific css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to make a Rails website with multiple static pages included.
Each page has a separate css and javascript that I don't want to load via application.js or application.css because I don't want to make it available to the rest of the site.

To organize the js and css, I was trying to put each page specific assets under their own folder in the js and css folder.

Kinda like this

```
- assets
  - javascripts
      -first
        - first.js
        - firststyle.js
      -second
        - second.js
        - secondstyle.js
      -third
        - third.js
        - thirdstyle.js
```

What would be the best way to call these files in rails.

I tried using the  in application and then including the js at the bottom of the static page, but there's an error because it looks for the js file in the root javascripts folder, and not its sub folders.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/gemgento/rails_script. This gem is a way that you can use page specific coffeescript without including everything into each page view. There are several different ways of doing page specific JS.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the html content of each page with `< div class="<%= params[:action]%>">` and `< div id="<%= params[:action]%>">`.
Thus all elements on individual pages would descend from classes and id's like **first** ,**second** etc. Use this in your respective CSS and JS files for specific pages. Thus **first.css.scss** would have **.first {...}** as the outermost nest.
This presumes that you are using a **static_pages_controller** with actions like **first** etc.